# How to add json inner tag some values each iteration?

Tags: python, json

import json

```
myjson = {'msg':[]}
d = {}
d['phrase'] = "event1"
d['start'] = "11.22.2018"
d['end'] = "11.28.2018"
myjson.get('msg').append({'phrase': d})
output = json.dumps(myjson)
print(output)
```

I tried this code for my problem. 
But there is an error.

```
{
  "msg": [
    {
      "phrase": {
        "phrase": "event1",
        "start": "11.22.2018",
        "end": "11.28.2018"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to take phrase value to the outer tag.

```
{
  "msg": [
    {
      "phrase": "event1"{
        [
          {
            "start": "11.22.2018",
            "end": "11.28.2018"
          },
          {
            "start": "11.22.2018",
            "end": "11.28.2018"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My data consist some events and events has start-end values more than one.

Can i add 1 start-end values to the event each iteration? 
How can i get such a json object below?

Comment: Your second json is syntactically wrong. `dict` cannot come next to `"event"`, and there is no comma between two `dict` which contain start-end values.

Comment: Yeap, I fixed it.

Comment: The project that i work on, the result format which want from me is exactly this format. I'm stuck with this issue.

Comment: So you want associate a `json` to a `value` of another `json` that is enclosed in a list. Why not use `event1` as a key instead of phrase and iterate through it? It's easier to implement a json as a value

Comment: Actually, I have many phrases that have a description word (phrases), a start date and a end date. But some phrases are repeated in my old json file. I want to bring together them( group by). The problem convert to this "one phrase have more than one start-end dates"